# "Source array was not long enough" Error registering BsonClassMap conventions in mongodb with C# driver

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

In the following code:

```
var myConventions = new ConventionProfile();
myConventions.SetIgnoreExtraElementsConvention(new AlwaysIgnoreExtraElementsConvention());
BsonClassMap.RegisterConventions(myConventions, (type) => true);
```

whenever it calls RegisterConventions, we are getting the following error, but it is very intermittent and random, and so it's very hard to troubleshoot.

> "Source array was not long enough. Check srcIndex and length, and the
>   array's lower bounds."

A few times we've purged our collections and that's fixed it, but the last few times, we purged and still had to then restart the windows service.  Then we could use our application and create records and collections to our hearts' content.

I'm thinking perhaps an array in one or more of our mapped class's array properties is getting initialized inconsistently, but I'm drawing a blank on next steps to take.  I could perhaps use a field initializer or initialize it in the constructor, but I don't want to start mucking with mongo api's mapping magic.  Also, we haven't seen this error in at least a week, so if I made some sort of fix and left it in there, I'll have no way of knowing if it actually fixed the problem or not.

Please help!  Thanks!

Comment: Which version of the driver are you using?

Comment: When the errors happened we were using 1.7.0.4714.  I have since upgraded us to 1.8.2.34 in our trunk branch to try and help fix the problem.  Our release branch is still on the 1.7x version. Like I said earlier, it shows up inconsistently.  We haven't seen it occur in either branch in about a week, and I just upgraded the trunk yesterday.

Comment: That's odd, `RegisterConventions` (which is obsolete btw) merely calls `ConventionRegistry.Register()` which simply adds a convention pack to a static `List`. As far as I know, that exception message you posted comes from `Array.Copy`. Maybe this is a threading-related bug. That would explain that it's byzantine. Maybe you can deploy the .pdb with the driver and provide a stack trace of the exception, or compile against the driver source to get a clearer picture.

Comment: Thanks, mnemosyn!  The next time the error happens, I will copy the whole stack track along with the pdb and dll.  I can rebuild from source, sure.  I'm also hoping I can use the source of the driver and attach the process and debug into the driver and find where the error is actually happening.  Once the error occurs, it is repeatable 100% of the time until we do our workarounds to clear it.